# creating a system that 'unlocks' when the timer reaches 0

Tags: python-3.x, time, locking

I'm working on a script where there is this timer and a user enters a duration e.g 2days: 2hoursd : 2minutes: 2seconds and when the timer hits 0 the word "unlocked" appears

I am absolutely lost and have no clue where to begin

ide show some code but I'm honestly lost

the user enters a duration
timer ticks down
timer reaches 0
word "unlocked" appears

Comment: What do you mean by "appears"? Is it only a print statement to stdout? Is the script running throughout the 2days?

Comment: sorry, grammatical error, no the word "unlocked" would be printed as an output

Comment: Is parsing the duration part of the problem?

Comment: the exercise I'm working on doesn't mention it, it literally lost on what to do, where to start, etc

Comment: Please make clear of what you want to have first, a detailed step by step actions of desired scenario may help

Comment: I thought I did, so basically a user enters a duration, the clock counts down and when it hits 0 then 'click' it outputs the word "unlocked"

Comment: What do you mean by 'click' here? What is clicked? Or is it sound?

Comment: At least tell us what you have tried first, before looking for answer .

Comment: sorry for the weird stuff, I finally recovered from a hangover, click is just like what a lock sounds line when it's unlocked

Answer (score 0):

The start_timer function starts a blocking timer which sleeps for one second each, until the defined duration has been reached. Additionally, if you run the script as main, it asks for user input to set the timer.

```
import datetime
import time


def start_timer(days=0, hours=0, minutes=0, seconds=5):
    t0 = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=days, seconds=seconds, minutes=minutes,
                               hours=hours)
    t1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    while (t1 - t0) < delta:
        time.sleep(1)
        t1 = datetime.datetime.now()

    print("Unlocked")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    days = float(input("Days? "))
    hours = float(input("Hours? "))
    minutes = float(input("Minutes? "))
    seconds = float(input("Seconds? "))
    start_timer(days=days, hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)
```